# How to add a translation service to QTranslate (ver 6.7.5.1) app?

Tags: qtranslate

In particular I'd like to add "Reverso context" to other translation services already present in the default menu (Google, Microsoft, Babylon, DeepL et cetera).
Thank very much in advance.